# word processing with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ms-office

I'm new to office development and want to create a simple application that :

- opens a word 2007-2010-2013 template.
- reads each and every placeholder.
- fills each one with the appropriate data.

However, how can I create a placeholder in a word template ?
How can I list placeholders and fill them using VB 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing word documents can be done in multiple ways. The easiest is probably from Inside Word itself. Microsoft provides a package called Visual Studio Tools for Office which can be used to integrate a plugin directly into word itself. You're probably looking for the [Word Content Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto2/archive/2007/01/16/updated-content-control-topics-for-the-visual-studio-code-name-orcas-january-ctp.aspx) feature. And that could be used with [XML data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398244.aspx).

You can also host Word in your own application and then interact directly with the loaded document using the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx). These managed classes are a wrapper around the COM objects that Office exposes. The XML data binding features are available through PIO as well. Look at the Word XML example which can [be downloaded from this samples page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms247298(v=office.11).aspx). Primary interop assemblies are only supported in Interactive applications. [Microsoft does not support running Office applications from a server/service application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

If you can limit yourself to the new XML Document standard you can extract the content from the document as XML and manipulate these directly (requires quite a bit of knowledge about the Word Document structure). [The Packaging class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) structure provided by the .NET framework contains everything needed to extract the document parts, once extracted it's simple XML. Or you could use an open source wrapper around the XML document format, such as [the open source DocX library](http://docx.codeplex.com/). A template field could simply be a special text like `{{TEMPLATE FIELD:FieldName}}`.

There are also a number of commercial libraries available, some with built-in mail-merge features. I personally have good experience with [Aspose.Words. Their documentation on Mailmerges can be found here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/About+Mail+Merge+in+Aspose.Words).

Comment: If you decide to use content control data binding, or legacy MERGEFIELD, https://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/ can do the "filling" for you. The examples are in C#, not VB.NET, but that ought not be a problem for you.